# Search Crawls are stopping with error of Access

Tags: central-administration, sharepoint-search, access-denied

I have a Newly configured SharePoint farm, which was due to data center migration. While setting up the search i have below errors logged. Tries all of the available fixes nothing worked.Default content access have all required permission and web application also have my account with full control and full read permission.

Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled. ( SearchID = EDBF5BA7-F978-427F-A3BB-75FFE55B0C80 )

Answer (score 0):

Does the "default account for crawling" as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/change-the-default-account-for-crawling) have the "Full Read" permission to the "Web Application"? Based on your description, it seems these are two different accounts. Also, you say data center was migrated, but you've not described how databases were migrated.

Comment: We did server replication so everything copied to a new server

Answer (score 0):

After all this investigation, I thought of a refreshing search service, and that made magic. The crawl started to work without issue.
Here is solution for refreshing service.

https://www.kieferconsulting.com/2015/01/10/sharepoint-2013-search-fixing-the-search-service-after-the-index-drive-fills/